# Take all prime numbers less than a big integer in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

I want to take all prime numbers less than a big integer (eg: 123456789012345).                                                                               Following code works for integers. But for big integer numbers not works. obj.runEratosthenesSieve(upperBound);---here mark as error. How to change it for big integer like 123456789012345.

```
   import java.math.BigInteger;
    public class Prime_Numbers {

                public void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
                      int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);
                      boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];
                      for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
                            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                                  System.out.print(m + " ");
                              for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)
                                        isComposite[k] = true;
                            }
                      }
                      for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++)
                            if (!isComposite[m])
                                  System.out.print(m + " ");
                }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  BigInteger  upperBound = new    BigInteger("123456789012345");
  Prime_Numbers obj = new Prime_Numbers();
  obj.runEratosthenesSieve(upperBound); -------------------????
    }}
```

Comment: You _could_ - but it's only **probable**. But I would recommend a [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).

Comment: What are you going to do with these primes? Do you want to calculate them or just look them up? If you want to do a look up it might be easier to take a list of known primes from the internet and load those.

Comment: I only want to look them.Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I used sieve and edited above code again. But it is not works for big integers.

Comment: Do you have an idea how many primes there are below 76379087654367076545667776? It would take many PB to store them all.

Comment: I want to take a prime numbers below 123456789012345. Actually, I have not an idea how many prime numbers below 123456789012345.

Comment: Well, below the new bound are 3-4 trillions primes. To store them all requires more than 10 TB of storage. So still not very practical. What do you plan to do with the list of primes? To test if a number in this range is prime or not is easy to do, no need to have a list.

Comment: I only want to take and print all prime numbers below 123456789012345.  I need to write a computer program for following question, -------Answer all prime numbers N  ,   
Satisfying N≤ 123456789012345

Comment: Do a few simple calculations: using your current algorithm, how large would the sieve `isComposite` have to be? does it fit into the memory of the computer?

Comment: I used as following code,                                                                                          public static void main(String[] args) {
  Prime_Numbers obj = new Prime_Numbers();
    obj.runEratosthenesSieve(123456789012345L); }  It gave out of memory error 1st. I solved it using -Xms512M. Now it gave following error. I can't solve it yet. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException . Thank you for your replies.